# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: jquery, undefined, jqxgrid

I am new to jqxGrid. I am trying to populate the grid after a ajax call to an PHP file and then reload. 
My code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "searchresults.php";
            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'ids', type:"string"},
                    { name: 'loc', type:"string" },
                    { name: 'name', type:"string"},
                    { name: 'tld', type: "string" },
                    { name: 'wc', type: "int" }
                ],
                id: 'id',
                url: url,
                root: 'data'
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#outgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 850,
                source: dataAdapter,
                //columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'IDs', dataField: 'IDs', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'LOCATION', dataField: 'loc', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'DOMAINS', dataField: 'name', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'TLD', dataField: 'tld', width: 90, cellsalign: 'right' },
                  { text: 'WORD COUNT', dataField: 'wc', cellsalign: 'right', minwidth: 100}
                ]
            });
        });
```

The error occurs at the line:

```
    $("#outgrid").jqxGrid(
```

I don't understand.
My dependencies are:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqx/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqx/jqxdatatable.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try with changing the sequence of files.

Comment: could you be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getting started example [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm) has a script link for a `jqxgrid.js` file (plus a load of add-ins).

I don't see that on yours? Do you definitely have one?

Note that jqxDataTable (which you do reference) is a completely different control, the startup guide for which is [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdatatable/jquery-datatable-getting-started.htm), and which is referenced using `$(...).jqxDataTable(...` instead of `$(...).jqxGrid(...`

Comment: after adding a few more dependencies I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jqxWidget' of undefined